# call omnicompletion from vimscript

Tags: vimscript, autocompletion

I'd like to automatically call the omnicompletion (that is triggered manually by `<Ctrl-X><Ctrl-O>`) from within a vimscript function.

I played around a bit with `execute 'normal! …'` and `feedkeys()`, but if I got it do actually do something, it always results in a literal `\<C-X>\<C-O>` in my document.

How can I call the omnicompletion from within a vimscript function?

**Edit:**

What I have tried so far (to simplify the example, I just jump to line 27, enter a new line below it and start omni-completion):

```
execute 'normal! 27Go\<c-x>\<c-o>'
```

```
  execute 'normal! 27Go'
  startinsert
  execute 'normal! \<c-x>\<c-o>'
```

```
  execute 'normal! 27Go'
  startinsert
  call feedkeys('\<c-x>\<c-o>')
```

**Edit 2:**

Hah, thanks to @ChristianBrabant I played around a bit more and found that `feedkeys()` should work, but I just used it wrongly! See my own answer below: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21713/21417

Comment: so what exactly did you try?

Comment: I just added some failed attempts

Comment: yes, double-quoting the keys should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feedkeys()` is the correct approach, but to respect the special keys, I must use double quotes (as mentioned in the [vimhelp](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29)):

```
  execute 'normal! 27Go'
  startinsert
  call feedkeys("\<c-x>\<c-o>")
```